# "Who said it best" is correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english

Can I write who said it best alone. For an example-  play j Cole's song ATM and write in status like "money makes people crazy, J Cole said it best" 
 Is that correct sentence?

Comment: Yes it is. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, as for example the ["Who wore it best?" meme](https://www.usmagazine.com/tag/celebrity-style-who-wore-it-best/) in celebrity fashion.

[image]

*However*, a more strict grammarian would say this is *incorrect*.  If comparing two things, you should instead ask:

> Who said it **better**?

(Edit) In your example, since you only list one item, there's no suggestion how many other items you want to compare it to.  So "Who said it best" is probably *better*.

Comment: No argument about *better* for the comparison of two things but I see no suggestion here that only two things are being compared?

Comment: @RonaldSole  Er ... I seem to have misread the question.  I thought there were more than two listed.